# How to map data which returns when making Api call in react-native

Tags: react-native, mapping

I am making an Api call where I will get the list of address.

```
const [address_line1, setAddress_line1] = React.useState([]);
```

I am able to get the result in the console.
Below is the snippet of my code after api is called:

```
if (result.status === 200 && result.data.status === "success") {
  for (let index = 0; index < 3; index++) {
    console.log(result.data.data[index].city);
    setAddress_line1(result.data.data[index].city);
  }
}
```

CONSOLE OUTPUT:

```
delhi
Mumbai
Pune
```

And I am trying to map this output in code :

```
<ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
  {address_line1.map((item, index) => (
    <TouchableOpacity
      index={index}
      onPress={() => setIndexSelect(index)}
      key={index}
    >
      <Text>{item}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  ))}
</ScrollView>;
```

But I am getting error:

```
address_line1.map is not a function
```

I know there is something wrong at the place where I am mapping my output, But I am not able to figure it out. I have been trying this for hours. I need some help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way

```
if (result.status === 200 && result.data.status === "success") {
  const data = [];
  for (let index = 0; index < 3; index++) {
    console.log(result.data.data[index].city);
    data.push(result.data.data[index].city);
  }
  setAddress_line1(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use reduce or map

```
useEffect(() => {
      if (result.status === 200 && result.data.status === "success") {
      const addresses = result.data.data.map(elem=>elem.city)
      setAddress_line1(addresses);
    }
    });
```

This way you loop all data and return the city